# The assembly xxx cannot be specified for both /link and /reference compiler options

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am getting the error in the title while trying to compile a C# project in VS2013.

It appears that I need to take a look at my compiler options and make sure the /link and /reference options aren't duplicating something.

Now if I could just FIND the compiler options.  I go to the projects properties, but I don't see anything in any of the tabs that gives access to compiler options.

How do I access the compiler options in VS2013?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into the issue myself.
I spent a while attempting to fix it, and along with what Hans Passant said, it doesn't make much sense having this situation.

After restarting Visual Studio, my issue was gone.

I could reproduce the issue if I attempted to toggle the `Embed Interop Types` - changed it from `True` to `False`.  This changed `Copy Local` to `True`.  Changing `Embed Interop Types` back again appeared to cause the issue, as if behind the scenes only one option was correctly changed.

Making sure those settings were how I wanted them, and then restarting Visual Studio seems to bring it back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The `/link` option is not controlled by the project properties.  It applies to an assembly reference, the ones you find in the References node of your project.

It will be used when the `Embed Interop Types` property of the reference is set to True.  Applicable to references to COM types libraries.  If it is False then `/reference` will be used.  Pretty hard to guess how you could have both /link and /reference turned on.  Programmers however have been getting into trouble by the outdated PIAs, the other name for "Embed Interop Types" is the "No PIA feature".  Might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when adding a reference (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) to my project that presumably interferred with one or more of these references: `COM Excel`, `COM Microsoft.Office.Core` and `COM VBIDE`. When I finally found a workaround in code that let me remove the first reference (it actually shares some functions and objects with the other three), the problem was solved.